# How to use snort with dpdk?

Tags: dpdk, snort

I have read a study that snort and dpdk are used together and snort performs better. However, I don't know much about dpdk and this confused me. Where can I find a resource for what I need to do to use dpdk and snort together? Or do you have an idea about it? Thank you.

Comment: COUPLE of things as you have mentioned `I have read a study that snort and dpdk are used together`, you should really ask the authors for those details. With respect to `using snort with dpdk`, my recommendation is use dpdk as input plugin for snort. this what I did to enable snort with DPDK from both physical NIC and virtual nic like vhost and memif. Hence can you clarify `that are you looking for guidelines or some pseudo code?`. If it is pseudo code, please share snort version, dpdk version, nic details, platform and code snippet to help you

Comment: In the study I read, they only talk about performance results, and there are no installation details.  Actually, I'm more looking for a general guide on using and installing these two applications together.  I think there is no such guide.  Thank you.

Comment: `In the study I read, they only talk about performance results, and there are no installation details` - you can still reach out to the authors if they can share the steps right? `I'm more looking for a general guide on using and installing these two applications together. ` surem please share the code snippet for `dpdk-inpu-plugin` to help you.